# Squid proxy: keep connection between squid and web server alive?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have very slow clients connecting over a squid proxy to the web. Some web servers, especially HTTPS, send a TCP FIN if they receive no data for some seconds. Can squid be configured to send keep alive packets to the web server to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended using Persistent HTTP with SSL turned on. Some server could not accept your next calls.